# Custom footer view for UITableView not fully visible

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios6

I implemented custom footer view, but unfortunately I can not scroll it to make all of it visible.

There is my code:

```
    UIView *footerView = [[UIView alloc] init];

    UIImageView *deliveryMainInfoImg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100)];
    deliveryMainInfoImg.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    deliveryMainInfoImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"delivery-cost.png"];
    deliveryMainInfoImg.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [footerView addSubview:deliveryMainInfoImg];

    CGFloat footerHeight = 0;

    NSString *txt = @"Some long text here ...";

    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(SCREEN_WIDTH - (3 * 10 + 100), SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    CGSize labelSize = [txt sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:SMALL_FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    footerHeight += labelSize.height;

    UILabel *deliveryMainInfoText =[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(deliveryMainInfoImg.frame.origin.x + deliveryMainInfoImg.frame.size.width + 10, 10, SCREEN_WIDTH - (3 * 10 + 100), labelSize.height)];
    deliveryMainInfoText.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    deliveryMainInfoText.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    deliveryMainInfoText.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:SMALL_FONT_SIZE];
    deliveryMainInfoText.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    deliveryMainInfoText.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    deliveryMainInfoText.minimumScaleFactor = SMALL_FONT_SIZE;
    deliveryMainInfoText.numberOfLines = 0;
    deliveryMainInfoText.text = txt;
    [footerView addSubview:deliveryMainInfoText];

    UIImageView *deliveryExtraInfoImg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, deliveryMainInfoText.frame.origin.y + deliveryMainInfoText.frame.size.height + 10, 100, 100)];
    deliveryExtraInfoImg.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    deliveryExtraInfoImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"delivery-info.png"];
    deliveryExtraInfoImg.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [footerView addSubview:deliveryExtraInfoImg];

    txt = @"Another long text ...";

    labelSize = [txt sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:SMALL_FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    footerHeight += labelSize.height;

    UILabel *deliveryExtraInfoText =[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(deliveryExtraInfoImg.frame.origin.x + deliveryExtraInfoImg.frame.size.width + 10, deliveryMainInfoText.frame.origin.y + deliveryMainInfoText.frame.size.height + 10, SCREEN_WIDTH - (3 * 10 + 100), labelSize.height)];
    deliveryExtraInfoText.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    deliveryExtraInfoText.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    deliveryExtraInfoText.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:SMALL_FONT_SIZE];
    deliveryExtraInfoText.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    deliveryExtraInfoText.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    deliveryExtraInfoText.minimumScaleFactor = SMALL_FONT_SIZE;
    deliveryExtraInfoText.numberOfLines = 0;
    deliveryExtraInfoText.text = txt;
    [footerView addSubview:deliveryExtraInfoText];

    self.tableView.tableFooterView = footerView;
```

And after running code, as I expected there is footer as I need, but part of it is not visible and when I'm trying to scroll it table only bounces.

Please help to solve this issue.

Thanks for any advance!

Comment: you gave the height of the footer view as SCREEN_HEIGHT,footer height and screen height are may be not equal,reduce the height in constraint try again....may be this will work....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace

```
UIView *footerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
```

with

```
UIView *footerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)];
```

And set the width and height variables to the correct values depending on the size of the contents.

Comment: No, I tried this but it not solve the problem, instead it adds extra space between my table view and footer.

Comment: I need footer that will scroll with my table view, so I do not use  -(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section, I use self.tableView.tableFooterView = footerView

Comment: Oh, sorry. Updated answer.